# jQuery ajax problems DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently using the jquery load() function to load text files that contain html code to insert it onto my current page on the fly. The problem I am having is within this new html code I have more buttons that I would like to assign onClick events to load further text files to the DOM but, it seems that because the document has loaded, the new html elements are not receiving the event handlers in my jQuery.

```
$(".a").click(function(){       
    $(".teamsContain").load("views/groups/groupA.txt");
});
```

This code loads a view that shows a list of teams within the group, when this has loaded I want the option to click an individual team to get details about game times which will be inserted into the DOM with another load() as below

```
$(".brazil").click(function(){      
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
});
```

But at this stage It wont work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Can you post an example of the problem on jsfiddle, or at least code snippets?

Comment: ok I edited the post to include some snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(".teamsContain").on('click','.brazil',function(){
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
})
```

REFERENCE

[delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Comment: yea I see how this should be but for some reason it wont work I will keep trying

Comment: Is `clicl` a new `event`?

Comment: @user3583717 is `.brazil` a link

Comment: oh my days! thanks it work! I understood what you were saying and frustrating me that it wasnt working, I never thought about the version of jquery. Thanks changing to jquery-1.11.0.min was the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'on' function? https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(".matches").on('click', '.brazil', function(){      
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
});
```

Also, if your click event targeted a unique attribute instead, such as an 'id', you could avoid duplication in your js.

Something like this...

HTML:

```
<a id="brazil" class='jsloadfile'>Click to load</a>
```

js:

```
$(".matches").on('click', '.jsloadfile', function(){   
    var filename = $(this).attr('id');   
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/"+filename+".txt");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to achieve this, for eg.

since you have *first one* working - but better to have it bound to a *known stable closest* DOM node, you can do something like this

```
$(".a").on('click', '.brazil', function(){      
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
});
```

to make sure, capture it in document level

```
$(document).on('click', '.brazil', function(){      
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For `event delegation` use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).on('click',".brazil",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default behaviour of anchor tag
    $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
}).on('click',".a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".teamsContain").load("views/groups/groupA.txt");
});
```

Comment: Yes thanks i see now about delegation I have used some of the examples above, I have used this

    $("td").on('click', '.brazil', function(){      
        $(".matches").load("views/upcomingGames/brazil.txt");
    });
But still not working :(

Comment: If `.brazil` and `.a` are `anchor tags` then use `event.preventDefault()`, see my updated answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/whileyman/FL9mQ/embedded/result/

this is on jfiddle im not used to jfiddle sorry if its wrong

Comment: I am using a table to contain the teams so not using anchor tags

Comment: You need to change your `jquery version` as on() works from `jquery-1.7 versions`, you should use `jquery-1.11` version, if you are not caring about `IE` then you can use the latest version of jquery.

Comment: oh my days! thanks it work! I understood what you were saying and frustrating me that it wasnt working, I never thought about the version of jquery. Thanks changing to jquery-1.11.0.min was the problem thanks :)